# storing large number of different length list of floats for rapid retrieval based on their metadata

Tags: python

I have a series of files named 001,002 etc. each with their own metadata fields (sometimes several fields)...

```
    001:
        values: [1.2, 3.4, 34.5]
        category: fruit
        rate: 50

    002:
        values: [4.2, 5.1, 5.1, 50.6, 10.5, 101.12]
        category: vegetable
        rate: 100

    003:
        ...
```

The files actually only have the `values` field and I have a dataframe for the category & rate data based on the filename, e.g. 001 --> fruit, 50 etc.

I am just wondering what pythonic data structure is best for this such that I can rapidly extract the `values` list for a rapid query. Ideally, this could be cloud based, e.g. using BigQuery but I don't know if there are better solutions. JSON naturally looks good, but I'm going to be having thousands of files with `values` lengths between 50 and 1000s. I'll want to get all those lists based on a select, e.g. 'all with category fruit'.

I thought about just putting all the files in a GCP bucket and having a SQL DB housing all the metadata for each file which then gives me a list of filenames (which contain the `values`) based on a given query -- then just do a bulk download each file that matches the criteria? Seems odd though. I'm familiar with GCP SQL and peewee, hdf5, json but just not sure how to tackle this one.

I don't know anything about elastic search but heard this is exactly what it was made for?

Any ideas are helpful thanks.